# Optional NTLM authentication in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ntlm

I have a site set up to authenticate users using NTLM in Apache on Linux using perl's Apache2::AuthenNTLM module. This works great when I require the authentication, but I want this to bypass the website's built-in login when the user can authenticate with NTLM and let them use the regular login if they can't. If users don't know their status, I think I need to make the NTLM authentication optional so that it is detected for users who have it, and everyone else sees the site as usual. I commented out 'require valid-user', but now the NTLM authentication isn't used at all. Is there a way to enable it without showing anything to users who don't authenticate?

This is the current htaccess:

```
PerlAuthenHandler Apache2::AuthenNTLM
AuthType ntlm
AuthName NTLMTest
#require valid-user
PerlAddVar ntdomain  "DOMAIN ADMIN ADMIN2"
PerlSetVar defaultdomain DOMAIN
PerlSetVar splitdomainprefix 1
PerlSetVar ntlmdebug 0
PerlSetVar ntlmauthoritative off
```

Answer (score 2):

A common pattern (used by Moodle) is to have a single second page that requires NTLM authentication, and have a first page that decides whether or not to direct you to that second page (based on your IP range, user agent, etc).

Comment: What if the trusted range of IP addresses has some computers that won't use NTLM, and you don't want to show an error message for them?

Comment: The idea is the same - you have a "gatekeeper" of sorts that offers choices for authentication. If you NTLM protect a file/directory - it is all-or-nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same requirement for my intranet websites and built a sample solution based on [crb's answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/96322/optional-ntlm-authentication-in-apache/96337#96337) for Apache with NTLM and PHP: [Optional NTLM authentication for a website on Apache with PHP](http://blog.stefan-macke.com/2011/04/07/optional-ntlm-authentication-for-a-website-on-apache-with-php)